# R: Matrix algebra in R: assign values to empty matrix from another matrix and table

Tags: r, matrix, sparse-matrix, matrix-multiplication

I have a sparse matrix of species presences and absences across many sites i.e. a sites by species matrix. I also have another table of the species grouped in clusters.

What I would like to have is a new matrix (also a sites x species matrix) that captures the count of each species per cluster.

I have a *for loop* that can do the job, but my original matrix is very big comprising several thousands of rows and columns, and a *for loop* will be computationally expensive.
Any idea on how to achieve this using **matrix algebra** or something more elegant?

My dataset is arranged as follows:

```
# 1. Species grouped in clusters

memb <- c(1,2,3,4,2,5)
names(memb) <- c("s1", "s2", "s3", "s4", "s5", "s6")
 

# 2. Number of clusters

z <- length(unique(memb))
z

[1] 5


# 3. Community matrix of species presence-absence across sites
d <- data.frame(grids=c("v1", "v1", "v2", "v2", "v3", "v3", "v3", 
                         "v1", "v3", "v4", "v2", "v1", "v4", "v3"),
                 sp=c("s1", "s3", "s2", "s3", "s1", "s2", "s3", 
                           "s4", "s4", "s4", "s5", "s6", "s5", "s5"))
M <- as.data.frame.matrix(table(d$grids, d$sp))

library(Matrix)
M <- Matrix(as.matrix(M), sparse=TRUE)
M

4 x 6 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
   s1 s2 s3 s4 s5 s6
v1  1  .  1  1  .  1
v2  .  1  1  .  1  .
v3  1  1  1  1  1  .
v4  .  .  .  1  1  .

# 4. create empty matrix collapsed proportional to the original diversity.
cluster_comm <- Matrix(0, dim(M)[[1]], z)
tmp_comm <- Matrix(0, dim(M)[[1]], dim(M)[[2]])
rownames(cluster_comm) <- rownames(M)
rownames(tmp_comm) <- rownames(M)
colnames(tmp_comm) <- names(memb)[order(memb, decreasing = FALSE)]
colnames(cluster_comm) <- colnames(M)[1:z]

# 5. For loop to add species to reduced empty matrix based on group membership
for (m in 1:dim(M)[[1]]) {
  tmp_comm[m, ] <- as.numeric(M[m, names(memb)[order(memb,decreasing = FALSE)]])
  for (i in 1:z) {
    names <- names(memb)[memb == i]
    cluster_comm[m, i] <- sum(tmp_comm[m, names])
    colnames(cluster_comm)[i] <- names[[1]]
  }
}

# Expected outcome
cluster_comm

4 x 5 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
   s1 s2 s3 s4 s6
v1  1  .  1  1  1
v2  .  2  1  .  .
v3  1  2  1  1  .
v4  .  1  .  1  .
```

Comment: Looking at your code I'm pretty sure there is an elegant way of achieving your result but I simply don't understand what you are trying to do. Can you give an example of your input data and explain how it is transformed into your exprcted output?

Comment: @MartinGal - I have reworded my request with hope to improve clarity on what I would like to achieve. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Starting from step 3, ugly solution that *may* be somewhat faster. Not sure whether the `merge` makes sense in your case though, test this with larger data. Changing `M` to `data.table` might also increase performance.

```
library(magrittr)
library(reshape2)
M <- as.data.frame.matrix(table(d$grids, d$sp))

M %>% cbind(.,rw = rownames(.)) %>%
      melt %>%
      merge(.,
             (memb %>% 
                   melt %>% 
                   cbind(., gr = rownames(.))), by.x = 'variable',
              by.y = 'gr',
              all.x = T) %>%
       dcast(., rw ~ value.y , value.var = 'value.x', fun.aggregate = sum )
```

Should return:

```
Using rw as id variables
  rw 1 2 3 4 5
1 v1 1 0 1 1 1
2 v2 0 2 1 0 0
3 v3 1 2 1 1 0
4 v4 0 1 0 1 0
```

## Sparse matrix:

Assuming `M` is a sparse matrix,

```
library(data.table)
m2 <- as(M, "dgTMatrix")
dt2 <- data.table(row=m2@i+1, col=m2@j+1, value=m2@x)

#either match names of memb with cols, or the other way around..
names(memb) %<>% gsub('s','',.)
```

```
dt2 %>% merge(., 
              memb %>%
                   melt %>%
                   cbind(., rw = rownames(.) %>% as.numeric),
              by.x = 'col',
              by.y = 'rw', 
              all.x=T ) %>% 
        dcast(., row ~ value.y , value.var = 'value.x', fun.aggregate = sum )
```

Should return:

```
row 1 2 3 4 5
1:   1 1 0 1 1 1
2:   2 0 2 1 0 0
3:   3 1 2 1 1 0
4:   4 0 1 0 1 0
```

Comment: Thanks @Nutle! It does what I want to achieve. However, because of the huge size of my matrix, I converted it to a sparse matrix as:
```M <- Matrix::Matrix(as.matrix(M), sparse=TRUE)```. When I applied your approach to the sparse matrix, I got an error as: ```Error in cbind2(x, .Call(dense_to_Csparse, y)) : 
  invalid class 'NA' to dup_mMatrix_as_geMatrix```. Hence my request for perhaps a matrix algebra approach.

Comment: We can rewrite the sparse matrix to a sparse data.table; it should use very similar amount of memory since it only tags the location of nonzero entries. I'll edit with an example, see if it works, @BHD

Comment: I have reworded the question to more clearly reflect my request. Please take a look to see if it makes more sense now.

Answer (score 0):

It's basically the same solution as Nutle's, but using `dplyr` and `tidyr`.

First I transform `memb` into a data.frame:

```r
memb <- c(1,2,3,4,2,5)
names(memb) <- c("s1", "s2", "s3", "s4", "s5", "s6")

membership <- data.frame(id=names(memb), group=memb)
```

Next I join it with `d`:

```
d %>% 
  left_join(membership, by=c("sp" = "id")) %>%
  count(grids, group) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from="group", 
              names_prefix="s", 
              names_sort=TRUE, 
              values_from="n", 
              values_fill=0)
```

which yields

```r
# A tibble: 4 x 6
  grids    s1    s2    s3    s4    s5
  <chr> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1 v1        1     0     1     1     1
2 v2        0     2     1     0     0
3 v3        1     2     1     1     0
4 v4        0     1     0     1     0
```

Comment: Thanks Martin! I applied your approach to the example data I provided, but got a different output:
```membership <- data.frame(group=c("v1", "v1", "v2", "v2", "v3", "v3", "v3", 
                        "v1", "v3", "v4", "v2", "v1", "v4", "v3"),
                id=c("s1", "s3", "s2", "s3", "s1", "s2", "s3", 
                     "s4", "s4", "s4", "s5", "s6", "s5", "s5"))```
Any other suggestion perhaps a matrix algebra approach?